# I-adjective in く form modifies a noun/adverb

Tags: grammar, parsing, song-lyrics, reading-comprehension, i-adjectives

In the song **宝物** by WANIMA, the chorus goes:

```
思いにまかせて
感じるまま描いて
まだ見えない明日へ
誰にも止められない
今この瞬間が紛れもなく全て。
```

`紛れもない` is in `く` form, which means it's modifiying a verb. However, `全て` is nowhere near a verb, but might be an adverb (which if it is, isn't modifying any verb)

I thought there might be a verb `全る` but I tried looking it up and there's none.

Is this just a common grammar rule break in songs? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 紛れもなく is like an adverb, but I think it is modifying not a single word but an entire clause, like an [English disjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_(linguistics)) (also known as [sentence adverbs](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043950/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/sentence-adverbs)). This 紛れもなく is emphasizing 今この瞬間が全て as a whole. A similar example is:

> 間違いなく彼は犯人だ。
> = 彼は間違いなく犯人だ。
> He is definitely the culprit.

Note that the ku-form of an adjective can also modify another adjective, e.g., 酷く臭い ("terribly stinky").

Comment: I see! Follow up, is the placement of 紛れもなく common Japanese? Or it's just an art or poetry kind of thing? ありがとう!

Comment: @Wreigh 紛れもなく is common, and it's almost a set phrase.